# Adding Apple in-app purchase to Electron HTML/JS app

Tags: javascript, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store, electron

Is there a way to add Mac App Store in-app purchase to Electron HTML/JS application? There are app store modules for Phonegap, Nativescript, ImpactJS etc but I can't seem to find anything for Electron or pure JS.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I've posted a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753835/implementing-in-app-purchase-in-an-electron-app-for-the-mac-app-store - if you figured anything out, then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in one of the similar [GitHub issues](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3745), you can try out customising [`nodobjc module`.](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC)

Answer (score 0):

A Node.js module for in-App-Purchase for iOS, Android, Amazon and Windows. https://github.com/voltrue2/in-app-purchase

Comment: This module is used only for validation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on this post, no one has really given a thorough answer.

I need to do in app purchases in my Electron app for the Mac App Store. It doesn't seem like anyone has figured out how to do that yet, so I've created a post with a 300 reputation points worth of bounty. If you think you can get more specific with how you'd do in app purchases, please let me know in there:

[Implementing in-app purchase in an Electron app for the Mac App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753835/implementing-in-app-purchase-in-an-electron-app-for-the-mac-app-store)